# Remove a specific data from a string

Tags: selenium

In my selenium project, I'm trying to remove the dynamic data from the below-mentioned string,
Example:
Success! fnmnt_tag_dstl: Tag Range added: ABC1300000001-1300000096

Here, The following data is kept on changing every time i.e ABC1300000001-1300000096 or XYZ1400000001-1400000048

I want to keep this data from string `"Success! fnmnt_tag_dstl: Tag Range added:"`as it is and replace/remove ABC1300000001-1300000096 or XYZ1400000001-1400000048 etc...

Actual string=> `Success! fnmnt_tag_dstl: Tag Range added: ABC1300000001-1300000096`

Expected String=> `Success! fnmnt_tag_dstl: Tag Range added:`

Comment: isn't this enough `actualtString.substring(0, actualtString.lastIndexOf(":"))`?

Comment: Ya, it's working. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Simply** follow **substring** function starting from **the beginning index** to **last index** of **colon (:)** operator

```
String actualValue = "Success! fnmnt_tag_dstl: Tag Range added: ABC1300000001-1300000096";
String expectedValue = actualValue.substring(0, actualValue.lastIndexOf(":")+1);
```

Comment: Thank you, The code you commented here is working perfectly.